# read json file and aggregate # value

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark

Read json file and count the unique # value as per User_Name.

I/P and O/P as per the below.

Input File :-

```
{
  "id": "0",
  "User_Name": "ANUP",
  "Tweet": "I love #BigData it is growing too fast #tech #spark #Hive"
}
{
  "id": "1",
  "User_Name": "ANUP",
  "Tweet": "I love #BigData it is growing too fast #tech #sqoop #HBASE"
}
{
  "id": "2",
  "User_Name": "Suraj",
  "Tweet": "My passion is #sport it help us to be #active #sport #fitness"
}
{
  "id": "3",
  "User_Name": "Gagan",
  "Tweet": "I love #BigData it is growing too fast #tech #spark #Hive"
}
```

o/p:-

```
user_name  Tweet
Anup         6
Suraj         4
Gagan         4
```

Comment: What's the question? :) Please provide some more details, you have provided the input, but we have no idea what you expect as the output.

Comment: What do you tried to do to solve the problem? What is your question? Can you provide a minimum example of your code for this problem?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to read json file in spark and count unique #value for each user ( username and tweet is tag/key in provided JSON file). Thank you

Comment: I need to read json file in spark and count unique #value for each user ( username and tweet is tag/key in provided JSON file). Can we achieve it without using UDF . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First part of your problem is reading from a JSON file which is pretty straight forward, just google it :)
About the second part, so the first thing you need is a regular expression that can recognize hashtags inside your strings, and extract them:

```scala
val getTagsPattern = "#(\\p{L}+)".r
```

Where L means any letter (not only English). Now let's use this regular expression inside a user defined function:

```scala
val getTags = udf[Set[String], String](tweet => {
  getTagsPattern.findAllMatchIn(tweet).map(_.group(1)).toSet
})
```

After extracting tags from tweets, you also need another aggregation function which can get tags of each row, and return a Set of all unique tags for a user:

```scala
val mergeUserTags = udf[Int, Array[Array[String]]](allTags => {
  allTags.foldLeft(Set.empty[String])(_ ++ _).size
})
```

What this UDF does is basically grab an input like `[[Spark, Hive], [Sports, Hive]]` and return `Set[Spark, Hive, Sports]` (eliminates non-unique tags). Now we have everything, just put them in the right order:

```scala
df.withColumn("Tags", getTags(col("Tweet")))
    .groupBy(col("User_Name"))
    .agg(mergeUserTags(collect_set(col("Tags"))) as "Tweet")
```

Results into:

```
+---------+-----+
|User_Name|Tweet|
+---------+-----+
|ANUP     |6    |
|Suraj    |3    |
|Gagan    |4    |
+---------+-----+
```